# Not getting result when passing the string values as xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Creating a test using Selenium webdriver, xpath is not working when passing string values.

Not getting the expected result.

```
String monthpath;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{    
     monthpath="//div[@id='PegasusCal-0']/div[@class='cal-body']/div/ul/li["+i+"]/a";
     path=dr1.findElement(By.xpath(monthpath));
     System.out.println(path.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```

Comment: What is your __expected result__?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `i` variable starts with value `0` and on first iteration you're searching for `li[0]` while in `XPath` first element has index `1` and you should search for `li[1]`

Just try to change your loop as

```
for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
```